# Displaying selection text in span

Tags: javascript, html

So let's say I have this code:

```
<span id="select_list">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="1">1</a></li>
        <li><a id="2">2</a></li>
        <li><a id="3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
<span id="selection"></span>
```

And let's also assume that there are a lot of list elements, ex. '4,5,6,7... etc'.
Can I get a html file, that is basically just text, that corresponds to the list element's ID (ex. 1.html, 2.html,... etc), to show in 'selection'?
If so how?
Thanks for your time. Hope I explained it well.

Comment: `span` is an `inline` element and shouldn't have `ul` or any block level elements inside of it. As far as your question, what is the action that should  occur? Would the user 'click' on the list-item?

Comment: Yes. The user would click the link in the list and the 1.html or whatever would appear in 'selection'.

Comment: I think you are talking about an `iframe` - see my updated answer.

Comment: Then I started thinking you wanted to AJAX the html in... so another update.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (jQuery) should work:

```
var list = $("#select_list");
var sel = $("#selection");

$("a", list).on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    sel.load(id+".html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="select_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="selection"></div>
```

i would use a div not span spans are for if you want to change the size of something particular like this:

```
  <li id="1" href="#"><a href="#"><span style="color: red; 
  font-size: 30px">1</span></a></li>
```

and from what i am understanding you want a selector to select them in css?

if so this is how:

```
 #select_list ul li:nth_child(1) {

 }
```

or

```
#select_list ul li#2 {

 }
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using data-attributes instead of IDs.

### HTML

```
<ul class='selection-list'>
    <li data-name='Dog'>Dog</li>
    <li data-name='cat.html'>Cat</li>
    <li data-name='45'>Fourty Five</li>
    <li data-name='Triangle'>Three sides</li>
</ul>

<div class="output js-output"></div>
```

### jQuery

```
var $output = $('.js-output');

$('.selection-list li').on('click', function() {
    var selectionValue = $(this).data('name');
    $output.text(selectionValue);
});
```

### CSS

```
.selection-list li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/cwvjbbe0/)

## iframe

I'm starting to think that you are asking for an iframe with dynamic source. The question is unclear. You may want to try and rewrite it. - Here is what I think you may be after...

### HTML

```
<ul class='selection-list'>
    <li data-url='http://reputable.agency'>Reputable Agency</li>
    <li data-url='http://perpetual.education'>Perpetual Education</li>
    <li data-url='http://example.com/index.html'>Example.com</li>
</ul>

<iframe src='http://example.com' class="output js-output"></iframe>
```

### JavaScript / jQuery

```
var $output = $('.js-output');

$('.selection-list li').on('click', function() {
    // get the 'data-url' from the element...
    var selectionValue = $(this).data('url');
    // put that data-url into the src attribute of the iFrame
    $output.attr('src', selectionValue);
});
```

#### Also..

Note that if you are using the same domain for all of these, you can build those urls differently to keep things simple.

```
<li data-url='index.html'>Example.com</li>

$output.attr('src', 'http://yoursite.com/' + selectionValue);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/nLmeb064/)

## AJAX

Now I'm wondering if you mean AJAX. Here is an example - but it's not tested because I don't have access to a bunch of relative URLs - but here is the basics - and should lead you to the right documentation.

### HTML

```
<ul class='selection-list'>
    <li data-url='index.html'>Reputable Agency</li>
    <li data-url='index.html'>Perpetual Education</li>
    <li data-url='index.html'>Example.com</li>
</ul>

<div class="output js-output"></div>
```

### JavaScript / jQuery

```
var $output = $('.js-output');

var getOtherPage = function(target) {
    $.ajax({
       url: target,
       success:function(response){
          $output.html(response);
       },error:function(){
          alert("error");
       }
    });
};

$('.selection-list li').on('click', function() {
    var selectionValue = $(this).data('url');
    getOtherPage(selectionValue);
});
```

Comment: Basically what I want to do is be able to display different html's inside a set space, allowing the user to choose which to view, without them actually following the link. I want it to be simple enough so that I can have quite a few options without being confusing to code.
So I think the iframe is a pretty good solution. Thanks for all the hard work you've put into this.